# Debugging boost source in visual studio

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2005

I'm using boost compiled libraries (e.g. program_options).
I want to be able to load the boost source code into the visual studio debugger (using 2005). Instead now I get that the source is not available do you want to look at the disassembler? message.

I set the Project->properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional library directory option to my boost win32.net directory.

I set the Project->properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include directory option to the root boost directory (boost-1.33.0).

Still I don't see the source come up in the debugger. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably also need to set up the "source files" directory. Offhand, I don't remember if you can do that on a per-project basis, or only in general. BTW, why are you using such an old release of Boost? 1.33 must be close to 5 years old now...

Comment: The usual problem: legacy code in a massive project. If I upgrade boost version it will break stuff in 10K places :) I actually managed to fiddle around with it enough and got it to work. Thanks for the help.